# In 2d space, given P1, and P2, find a perpendicular point (270 degrees) to the left of the line between P1, and P2

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a perpendicular point, P3, given a vector P1P2, and the distance between P2 and P3. Assuming the direction along the line P1 and P2 is 0 degrees, find the point 270 degrees to the left of P2. This is in 2d space.

[image: Example image]

Comment: $P_3 = P_2 + \begin{bmatrix} 0 &1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix} (P_2 - P_1)\frac {b}{\|P_2 - P_1\|}$

Comment: How would this change if I wanted to find the point to the right 90 degrees?

Comment: Ha,ha.  That is a clockwise rotation... When you build transformation matrix, think to yourself where to I want $(1,0)$ to go?  That is the first column.  And where do I want $(0,1)$ to go? That is your second column.

Comment: Can you put this in an answer so I can mark yours as correct?

Answer (score 0):

Take coordinates of $P_1$, $P_2$ and $P_3$ as $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2,y_2)$ and $(x,y)$ respectively. Then we have:$$P_1P_2=(x_2-x_1,y_2-y_1)\\P_2P_3=(x-x_2,y-y_2)\\P_1P_2.P_2P_3=0\to (x_2-x_1)(x-x_2)+(y_2-y_1)(y-y_2)=0$$
also $$(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2=b^2\to {x=x_2+\frac{(y_2-y_1)b}{P_1P_2}\\y=y_2-\frac{(x_2-x_1)b}{P_1P_2}}$$